Maximizing the number of generated triplets that are in a set
I don't have much math experience and feel out of my depth with this problem, so apologies in advance.
Given the sets $C$, $V$, and $S$ where $S \subseteq  C \times V \times C$:
Find sets $c \subseteq C, v \subseteq V$ such that $c \times v \times c \subseteq S$ and that the size of $c \times v \times c$ is maximized.
In other words, if $C$ and $V$ are alphabets and $S$ is the set of valid words of the form CVC, I would like to find the largest sub-alphabets $c$ and $v$ that only generate valid words.
A trivial example:
C: p t c
V: a i
S: pit, tic, tac, cat, tat, cac

Solution:
c: t c
v: a
Generated words: tac, cat, tat, cac

No valid word ends in p so it can be eliminated. Adding i would allow for tic, but would also lead to cit which is invalid.
I have no idea how to approach this problem, I have tried breaking it down into simpler terms to no avail. The closest problem I was able to find was this (the "maximum hyperclique in a 3-uniform hypergraph"), but it only uses a single alphabet and I don't know how to relate it to this problem. I've also never used graphs or hypergraphs, so I don't know where to start or if that is even the right place to look.

Do you have a larger instance of interest that you can share?

@RobPratt That was a mistake, thank you. I have a list of 4000 English syllables, but I'm not sure how I would share that or how helpful that would be.

So $|S|=4000$?  How big are $C$ and $A$?

C is 12 and V is 17

Hmm, $|C \times V \times C|=12^2 \cdot 17 = 2448 < 4000 = |S|$, so $S$ cannot be a subset of $C \times V \times C$.

@RobPratt Sorry. I meant 22, not 12.

OK, and do $C$ and $V$ overlap, or are they disjoint like in your example?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in C$, let binary decision variable $c_i$ indicate whether consonant $i$ is selected.  For $j\in V$, let binary decision variable $v_j$ indicate whether vowel $j$ is selected.  For $(i,j,k)\in S$, let binary decision variable $w_{ijk}$ indicate whether word $(i,j,k)$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize the number $$\sum_{(i,j,k)\in S} w_{ijk}$$ of selected words subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
w_{ijk} &\le c_i &&\text{for $(i,j,k)\in S$} \tag1\label1 \\
w_{ijk} &\le v_j &&\text{for $(i,j,k)\in S$} \tag2\label2 \\
w_{ijk} &\le c_k &&\text{for $(i,j,k)\in S$} \tag3\label3 \\
c_i + v_j + c_k &\le 2 &&\text{for $(i,j,k)\in (C \times V \times C) \setminus S$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Constraints \eqref{1} through \eqref{3} enforce the logical implication $$w_{ijk} \implies (c_i \land v_j \land c_k).$$  That is, if word $(i,j,k)$ is selected then consonants $i$ and $k$ and vowel $j$ must be selected.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces the logical implication
$$(i,j,k)\not\in S \implies \lnot (c_i \land v_j \land c_k).$$  That is, if $(i,j,k)$ is not a word then consonants $i$ and $k$ and vowel $j$ cannot all be selected.
For the problem data provided in the chat, with $|C|=22$, $|V|=17$, and $|S|=4149$, the maximum objective value turns out to be $8^3=512$, attained by the unique optimal solution
with selected consonants $\{B,D,G,K,L,N,S,T\}$
and selected vowels $\{AA,AE,AH,AY,EH,IY,OW,UW\}$.
